# C++ pointer ownership in path finding

Tags: c++, containers, smart-pointers

I am writing a path finding algorithm, so I have `TreeNode` that represents the nodes but in my algorithm, I have an `open` container that is a `priority_queue`, which allows fast retrieval of the highest priority node. I also need to check quickly if I already explored a given node, so I have a `closed` container that is a `set`.

Now the problem is: who owns what? where are my TreeNodes stored? The `open` and `closed` containers don't need to store the nodes themselves, they can just have a pointer to them, but where do I store the nodes then?

My idea is to store in these containers `weak_ptr<TreeNode>` and when I want to create a new TreeNode I use `make_shared<TreeNode>`? Or can I have a `vector<TreeNode>` that stores all the nodes and the other containers just store indices, so I avoid costly `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 2):

I would indeed separate the ownership of the objects from the algorithm itself.

In case you know for sure you will have a fixed number of nodes during the algorithm's execution, you can use `vector<TreeNode>` which is created once, fully, beforehand.
Then you can either use pointers to the elements or their indices and operate on those.
Pointers are slightly more flexible as then you can change the underlying storage container to something non-contiguous (e.g. `std::set`, or even store them in a `map` or something else entirely).
Then no extra visual and code overhead "pollutes" the algorithm code unnecessarily, and the ownership question is trivial, which is always a good thing.

Comment: But if I don't know how many nodes will be created during the search, what should I do?

Comment: The only thing to be wary of when resizing your vector is that pointers to relocated elements will be invalidated. So you can still use indices into the vector's elements (as long as you don't go removing elements without also updating the indices you keep) but not pointers. Amending that to `std::vector<unique_ptr<TreeNode>>` will allow your algorithm to operate on (raw, non-owning) pointers to the nodes and you can resize your vector inside your algorithm without invalidating those.